# "their/her/... one of" instead "one of their/her/..."

Tags: usage

I am somewhat confused to use these two forms in a sentence.

> you can arrange a party at [**one of their** houses] /[ **their one of** the houses]?

Normally I use the first form but what If I write the second one in a sentence, will this usage be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form is fine, but the second form is incorrect for this meaning. If you can add a bit more information on the context, that would help clarify the meaning you are looking for.

However, here are some examples:

> You can arrange a party at [their/her/his] house

The above implies that you are talking about a specific house, belonging to one or more people. E.g. Alice has a big house, and always lets friends have parties there. If you ask her, I'm sure you can arrange a party there (at her house).

> You can arrange a party at one of their houses

The above could mean there are several people (or groups of people), each of whom owns a house. E.g. you have five friends with houses who like hosting parties. If you ask them all, I'm sure you will be able to arrange a party at one of their houses.

> You can arrange a party at one of [their/her/his] houses

This could also mean one of the many houses belonging to one person (or one group e.g. a couple who own a house together). E.g. Charlie and Chris own three houses! They only live in one at a time, so you could probably arrange a party at one of their houses.

As for when you might use 'Their one of ...', here are some examples. It is not common, though, and it may not always sound natural. Generally, '[Their/her/his] one of the [thing]s' would imply that there is a known set of things, and you want to refer to the specific thing which belongs to (a) specific owner(s). By saying 'Their one of the [thing]s', you draw attention to the thing (through using 'one'), and the set of things (through using 'of the [thing]s'). You could say 'their [thing]', 'theirs' or 'Their one'. One of these shorter versions (use 'Their [thing]' if in doubt) would probably sound more natural in most cases.

E.g.:

> Chris and Charlie live in a big house. You want to hold a party but your house is too small. You could ask them if you could use [their house]/[theirs].
>
> Alice has a phone. Your phone is broken so you ask Alice if you can use [hers]/[her one]/[her phone].
>
> Bob lives on your street. Your house was really cheap but Bob's [one]/[one of the houses]/[house]/[] was a lot more expensive.

In the final example, you could say 'Bob's one of the houses' to highlight 'the houses' (=the houses on your street), and 'Bob's one' (the house belonging to Bob, which is familiar to you). However, it doesn't sound as natural as 'Bob's one' (informal), 'Bob's' (fairly informal), or 'Bob's house'.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder whether the second one is the same meaning as the first one. As you have said, its not the same with the regular usage, so is there any area to use [their/her/his] one of [..]?

Comment: I've added some examples. It does make sense to say 'their one of ...', and I've explained how it might be interpreted by editing my answer. However, it likely sounds less natural than 'their one'/'their [...]'/'theirs'. Hope that helps.